# Why does this code only work when run from inside Visual Studio but not otherwise?

Tags: c#

I have below code that works fine when I hit F5 in Visual Studio (both with a Debug or Release build), but when I run the EXE file directly, I get a exception:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: 未能比较数组中的两个元素。 ---> System.ArgumentException: Hey,C#,you give me a null?
   在 GeometricComposition.GCForm.DataForm.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GenerateTreeNodes>b__1(TreeNode a, TreeNode b) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\GCForm\DataFormGenerateDistance.cs:行号 124
   在 System.Array.FunctorComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.PickPivotAndPartition(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort(T[] keys, Int32 lo, Int32 hi, Int32 depthLimit, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort(T[] keys, Int32 left, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   --- 内部异常堆栈跟踪的结尾 ---
   在 System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)
   在 System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Sort(Comparison`1 comparison)
   在 GeometricComposition.GCForm.DataForm.GenerateTreeNodes(String rootFormat, String childFormat, FuncRef`3 getChildNodes, Func`3 comparePairs) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\GCForm\DataFormGenerateDistance.cs:行号 121
   在 GeometricComposition.GCForm.DataForm.DisplayPairsTreeInvoke() 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\GCForm\DataFormGenerateDistance.cs:行号 100
   在 GeometricComposition.GCForm.DataForm.GenerateData(GCFile file) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\GCForm\DataForm.cs:行号 44
   在 GeometricComposition.GCForm.DataForm.HandleSelectedFileChanged(Object sender, SelectedFileChangedEventArg e) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\GCForm\DataForm.cs:行号 73
   在 GeometricComposition.SelectedFileChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, SelectedFileChangedEventArg e)
   在 GeometricComposition.MainForm.OnSelectedFileChanged() 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\MainForm.cs:行号 68
   在 GeometricComposition.MainForm.WorkDockPanel_ActiveContentChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\GeometricComposition\MainForm.cs:行号 59
   在 WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.OnActiveContentChanged(EventArgs e) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.FocusManager.cs:行号 577
   在 WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.FocusManagerImpl.RefreshActiveWindow() 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.FocusManager.cs:行号 402
   在 WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.FocusManagerImpl.HookEventHandler(Object sender, HookEventArgs e) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.FocusManager.cs:行号 354
   在 WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.FocusManagerImpl.LocalWindowsHook.OnHookInvoked(HookEventArgs e) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.FocusManager.cs:行号 58
   在 WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPanel.FocusManagerImpl.LocalWindowsHook.CoreHookProc(Int32 code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) 位置 h:\Projects\C#\GeometricComposition\WinFormsUI\Docking\DockPanel.FocusManager.cs:行号 78
   在 System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetFocus(HandleRef hWnd)
   在 System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.FocusActiveControlInternal()
   在 System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Active(Boolean value)
   在 System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmActivate(Message& m)
   在 System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   在 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   在 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   在 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is not my first time or project where I meet this problem, but this time I decided to figure out  the cause.

The full original code is:

```
...
...
GenerateTreeNodes("P", "FD", GetChildNodesByPitch, ComparePairsDistance);
...
...
private void GenerateTreeNodes(string rootFormat, string childFormat,
        FuncRef<int, string, List<TreeNode>> getChildNodes,
        Func<GCFacePointPair, GCFacePointPair, int> comparePairs)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < fpps.Count)
        {
            TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(fpps[i].ToString(rootFormat));
            List<TreeNode> childNodes = getChildNodes(ref i, childFormat);
            childNodes.Sort((TreeNode a, TreeNode b) =>
            {
                if (a == null || b == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Hey,C#,you give me a null?");
                return comparePairs((GCFacePointPair)a.Tag, (GCFacePointPair)b.Tag);
            });
            rootNode.Nodes.AddRange(childNodes.ToArray());
            FacePointTreeView.Invoke((Func<TreeNode, int>)(FacePointTreeView.Nodes.Add), rootNode);
        }
    }

    private List<TreeNode> GetChildNodesByPitch(ref int index, string format)
    {
        List<TreeNode> childNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        GCPitch curr = fpps[index].Point.ID;
        while (index < fpps.Count && fpps[index].Point.ID == curr)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(fpps[index].ToString(format));
            node.Tag = fpps[index];
            childNodes.Add(node);
            index++;
        }
        return childNodes;
    }

    private int ComparePairsDistance(GCFacePointPair a, GCFacePointPair b)
    { return Math.Sign(a.Distance - b.Distance); }
```

---

PROBLEM is BEFORE `Sort()` there is no null in `childNodes`
BUT AFTER `Sort()` I got a null

---

Obviously, the `Tag` property must be set.

---

1. It give my comparison a null value. Why?
2. As the code shows, before calling `Sort()`, there is no null value in `childNodes`,
   but after `Sort()`, there is a null value. Why?
3. What is the difference between a Debug build and a Release build?

4.Is a C# bug? I have meet a C# bug before.

Comment: no...I have clean up and rebuild the solution lots of time, and I did not touch anythings...

Comment: Perhaps the environment in which your program is running differs.

Comment: Can't you get a copypaste of the exception as text? But if image is only thing you can get, add it as link, and someone with more rep can edit it in.

Comment: Where do you call GetChildNodesByPitch? GenerateTreeNodes does not call that, it uses the passed-in FuncRef<>. Also, the Sort occurs inside a loop. What is the value of fpps.Count?

Comment: oh,outside a code call it           'code'(GenerateTreeNodes("P", "FD", GetChildNodesByPitch, ComparePairsDistance);)

Answer (score 2):

Your code checks whether there are any null TreeNodes. However, it is also casting TreeNode.Tag to GCFacePointPair:

```
return comparePairs((GCFacePointPair)a.Tag, (GCFacePointPair)b.Tag);
```

I suspect there may be TreeNodes whose Tag has not been set. Perhaps you should add to the test, to help you debug this:

```
        if (childNodes.FindIndex((TreeNode n) => 
            { return n == null; }) != -1)
            throw new Exception("null 0");
        if (childNodes.FindIndex((TreeNode n) => { 
            return !(n.Tag is GCFacePointPair); }) != -1)
            throw new Exception("Tag not set");
```

Comment: thanks,but I have check it before,there is no problem

Comment: the big problem is before the Sort(),there is no null value in the childNodes,but after the Sort(),I get a null value in childNodes

Comment: You should paste the exact Exception and line number into your question. This will help you get a better answer. If the exception is not visible in your program output, you can add a try/catch block and print it (or use a MessageBox as you have done above.)

Comment: why it has different behavior in Release Version

Answer (score 1):

well, I have solved this problem...although I still do not know why...
I promise there is no bug in MY code...
how to solve?
here is the code:

```
...
...
GenerateTreeNodes("P", "FD", GetChildNodesByPitch, ComparePairsDistance);
...
...
private void GenerateTreeNodes(string rootFormat, string childFormat,
            ActionRef2<SortedSet<TreeNode>,int, string> getChildNodes,
            Func<GCFacePointPair, GCFacePointPair, int> comparePairs)
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (index < fpps.Count)
            {
                TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(fpps[index].ToString(rootFormat));
                SortedSet<TreeNode> childNodes =
                    new SortedSet<TreeNode>(
                        Comparer<TreeNode>.Create((TreeNode a, TreeNode b) =>
                        {
                            return comparePairs((GCFacePointPair)a.Tag, (GCFacePointPair)b.Tag);
                        }));

                getChildNodes(ref childNodes, ref index, childFormat);

                /*childNodes.Sort((TreeNode a, TreeNode b) =>
                {
                    return comparePairs((GCFacePointPair)a.Tag, (GCFacePointPair)b.Tag);
                });*/

                TreeNode[] nodes = new TreeNode[childNodes.Count];
                childNodes.CopyTo(nodes);
                rootNode.Nodes.AddRange(nodes);
                //rootNode.Nodes.AddRange(childNodes.ToArray());

                FacePointTreeView.Invoke((Func<TreeNode, int>)(FacePointTreeView.Nodes.Add), rootNode);
            }
        }

        private void GetChildNodesByPitch(ref SortedSet<TreeNode> childNodes, ref int index, string format)
        {
            GCPitch curr = fpps[index].Point.ID;
            while (index < fpps.Count && fpps[index].Point.ID == curr)
            {
                TreeNode node = new TreeNode(fpps[index].ToString(format));
                node.Tag = fpps[index];
                childNodes.Add(node);
                index++;
            }
        }

        private int ComparePairsDistance(GCFacePointPair a, GCFacePointPair b)
        { return Math.Sign(a.Distance - b.Distance); }
```

noted that I just replace the `List<T>` with `SortedSet<T>` and take some adjustment
so after `Add` all nodes, it is sorted.

I still wonder what happen in Release build...
who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

to find what is wrong, check the values of the node that might be wrong

```
var nullIdx = childNodes.FindIndex((TreeNode n) => { return n == null; });
if (nullIdx >= 0)
{
    var nullChild = childNodes[nullIdx];
    // todo nullIdx-1 and nullIdx+1 to maybe check what went wrong
    throw new Exception("null 1");
}
```

Comment: MSDN says:The zero-based index of the first occurrence of an element that matches the conditions defined by match, if found; otherwise, –1   [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx)